# Python type hints for custom module level constants

Tags: python, constants, alias, type-hinting, typing

I am trying to add type hints to my classes, but I am struggling with this particular issue with module level constants. In the following example, I've substituted my constants with BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR, WHITECAR - simply assume that my whole program evolves around these 4 constants, which is why I am defining those explicitly.

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import List, Union, TypeVar

# I define CarTypeRef from id and name
CarTypeRef = namedtuple("CarType", "id name")


# I define possible car types by id and name
BLUECAR: CarTypeRef = CarTypeRef (1, 'Blue Car')
REDCAR: CarTypeRef = CarTypeRef (2, 'Red Car')
YELLOWCAR: CarTypeRef = CarTypeRef (3, 'Yellow Car')
WHITECAR: CarTypeRef = CarTypeRef (4, 'White Car')
"""Car type init with id-name"""

# 1. try: this does not work:
CarType = TypeVar("CarType", BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR, WHITECAR)
"""Type alias for possible car types"""

# 2. try: this (type alias) does also not work:
CarType = Union[BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR, WHITECAR]

# I later use the following list
# e.g. to loop through available car types
CARTYPES: List[CarType] = [
    BLUECAR,
    REDCAR,
    YELLOWCAR,
    WHITECAR]
"""Available car types"""
```

For both type definitions I get the following output at runtime:

```
> 1.try: TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got CarType(id=1, name='Blue Car').
> 2. try: TypeError: TypeVar(name, constraint, ...): constraints must be types. Got CarType(id=1, name='Blue Car').
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I create custom type-checking for these 4 constants?

Note: of course, I could simply use strings (e.g.: "bluecar", "redcar", ..), but since these 4 constants appear so often in my code, I wanted to be a little bit more explicit - both for code legibility and also for static type testing.

Comment: `BLUECAR`, `REDCAR`, etc. are *values*, not *types*. Take a look at [`enum.Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum), because that's exactly what you're (poorly) re-implementing with this code.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Aran-Fey for pointing me in the right direction. I haven't heard of Enums in python yet. I was able to reduce my code significantly, it is now only:

```py
class CarType(Enum):
    """Available car types"""
    BLUECAR = 1
    REDCAR = 2
    YELLOWCAR = 3
    WHITECAR = 4
```

And I can get even get human readable text without specifying an `str` as name, e.g.:

```py
>>>> print(Car.REDCAR.name.lower().capitalize())
Redcar
```

.. although it is a bit more convoluted.

Furthermore, I can't import BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR or WHITECAR directly, which means I always have to refer to those with their full Enum class, e.g.

```py
from .typedef import CarType
if car_type in [CarType.BLUECAR, CarType.REDCAR, CarType.WHITECAR]:
    paint_yellow(car)
```

.. which is far more code than:

```py
from .typedef import BLUECAR, REDCAR, WHITECAR

if car_type in [BLUECAR, REDCAR, WHITECAR]:
    paint_yellow(car)
```

[Update]

While the Enum-approach was good, I ended up using simple string constants, which better fit my purposes, e.g.:

```py
BLUECAR: str = "Blue Car"
REDCAR: str = "Red Car"
YELLOWCAR: str = "Yellow Car"
WHITECAR: str = "White Car"

CARTYPES: List[str] = [BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR, WHITECAR]
```

.. because I could do:

```py
from .typedef import BLUECAR, REDCAR, YELLOWCAR, WHITECAR, CARTYPES

for car_type in CARTYPES:
    ...
..
if car_type in [BLUECAR, REDCAR]:
    ...
```

I understand that this is specific to how these variables are used, and perhaps the car-type example doesn't really suit to describe my real implementation scenario.